# Why do you have to use .class in Java to get the Class object? Why not just the class name like in Ruby?

Tags: java

Why do you have to use `.class` in Java to get the `Class` object? Why not just the class name like in Ruby?

I know `Ruby` and `Java` are very different. But it seems counter-intuitive to actually have to type out `.class` when you have already typed out the class name.

If there are static methods on the class, then you type `MyClass.staticMethod()`, not `MyClass.class.staticMethod()`.

This might be a pointless question, but I wanted to see if there was anyone out there that could enlighten me.

Comment: Because the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)?

Comment: How would you distinguish between static methods on MyClass and methods on Class?

Comment: @RC - Ah... ok... see us Rubyists don't know too much about... um, formal language specifications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because classes and variables do not share a namespace in Java, which means you can have variables which have the same name as an existing class. This statement:

```
String Integer = "Integer";
```

is completely legal and creates a new String variable named `Integer` even though there is [a class `Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

An example which shows that using the class name as a Class object would be ambiguous:

```
Class Integer = "Integer".getClass(); 
System.out.println(Integer.getName());
```

Would this print "java.lang.Integer" or "java.lang.String"?

*But what if the variable `Class Integer` would simply shadow the definition of the `class Integer`?*

Do you consider shadowing a good thing? It often creates confusion and nasty surprises. But this is of course debatable. Also, `new Integer(42)` (constructor String(int) is undefined) now becomes a runtime error instead of a compile-time error.

*But what if we would simply forbid to name variables after existing classes?*

There are quite a lot of classes in the standard library. That would really shrink down the namespace of available variable names.

*But then what if we only forbid to name variables after classes which are `import`ed in the current .java file?*

...and then you add a new import and your code doesn't compile anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of reasons. The first was mentioned in the comment by peeskillet, where the compiler has to deal with instantiation of a new type of the object:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
```

The other is that there is actually an object (`Class<?>`) which represents a class of a type - its not just "that class". This can be used as an argument to other methods, so you need a way to distinguish between an attempt to create a new instance (above) and a reference to the `Class<?>` of the object.

Whether this was a good idea, or if it could be simplified is certainly up for debate :) Note that Java arose from strong roots in C/C++, so there are most certainly things within it that came from that line of thinking - there's always the possibility for "seemed like a good idea at the time"